# Create an event for all of the RadioButton's GroupName in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a click event that when a radiobutton was clicked/checked/ticked I need to know what is the value of that radiobutton and what groupname does it belongs to.

```
$("input[name='tstProCon'], input[name='thsProCon'], input[name='thProCon']").click(function () {
var myVal1 = $(this + ":checked").val();
alert(myVal1);
});
```

I used the above click event but it throws a jquery syntax error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='tstProCon'], input[name='thsProCon'], input[name='thProCon']").click(function () {
  var myVal1 = this.value;
  // or the complicated way ;)
  // var myVal1 = $(this).val();
  alert(myVal1);
});
```

The expression `$(this + ":checked").val();` is the problem. `this` is a (native, not jQuery!) reference to the DOM element which received the event. Obviously, you can't mix it with a string.

Comment: Thanks and You should use `this.value` as he was trying to get the value of the element.  From OP: _I need to know what is the value of that radiobutton_

Comment: Nicely done. I forgot that I was already using this approach in my previous codes.

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    var myVal1 = $(this).prop("checked"),
        groupName =  $(this).attr("name");
        alert(myVal1  + groupName);
});
```

hope it helps.

Comment: hi after getting the groupname how can I get the value of which button was checked?

Comment: @jaegar: you want to get which radiobutton checked inside that groupname?

Comment: Thanks for your answer I finally get the thing that I needed!